# Can I make this CSS file more simple?

Tags: css

I've got a CSS that looks like this:

```
.title-separator {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5em, auto;
  border-width: @baseline;
}

.welcome-message {
  color: @home-page-title-color;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.nav-list-selected {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: @selected-nav-button-foreground-color;
  background-color: @selected-nav-button-background-color;
}

.mentor-dashboard {
  #mentor {
    .nav-list-selected
  }
}

.trainee-dashboard {
  #trainee {
    .nav-list-selected
  }
}

.connections {
  #connections {
    .nav-list-selected
  }
}

.staff {
  #staff {
    .nav-list-selected
  }
}

.leaderboards {
  #leaderboards {
    .nav-list-selected
  }
}
```

as you can see the `.nav-list-selected` is called multiple times. Is there a way I can reduce the amount of code in here so I only need to call it once? All of these classes/ids are calling it.

Also, my second question is: I am wanting to remove the `id's` on each of these classes because they are basically useless. However, when I try to remove the id and replace the class name with the id, it highlights all of them when I click my tab. It's almost as if the class is overwriting everything, but for some reason if I keep it the way it is, it does not do that. Any ideas? This is what it looks like:

if I only have the class it overwrites everything when highlighted (as seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JeZK.png ) When keeping the id's in, it does not overwrite this and instead looks like this when highlighted ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFe4J.png )

Comment: Note sure this is the place for this question? Perhaps CodeReview? Why IDs **and** classes?

Comment: Just group the selectors. That's the only suggestion I'd give for simplification.

Comment: The first question is absolutely appropriate for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). The second is IDE/Syntax debugging, which wouldn't be.If you decide to move it, I'd stick with just "How can I make this simpler/better/more readable etc."

Comment: @Harry How can I group the selectors?

Comment: @JohnSmith: Like `.mentor-dashboard #mentor, .trainee-dashboard #trainee, .connections #connections {.nav-list-selected}`. You could make it more complex by using loops, guards etc etc but don't do that.

Comment: @Harry I was told to use either extended or mixins by a colleague. If I do it like the way you said, is that a mixin or extended?

Comment: @JohnSmith: That's actually neither but can loosely be classified as a mixin. Extend is more useful when each of those will have its own properties in addition to common ones. Here since all of them are going to have the same set, extend is not really needed.

Comment: @Harry So I would want to use a mixin then? What might that look like?

Comment: @JohnSmith: What I meant to say is that you need neither mixins nor extends. All you need is to define a CSS class `.nav-list-selected` (like you have already done) and call it within the selector group.

Comment: @Harry In my case what would the selector group be? And how would I call it? I thought I was already calling .nav-list-selected in my selector groups

Comment: Yes you were already calling it correctly but you just weren't grouping the selectors in a comma separated format like in my earlier comment.